# Where to start writing a Postgres data access layer for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm writing an Express application with Node and would like to abstract my code a little, specifically data access stuff.  I want to avoid just installing one of the ORMS as I've been advised to not use an ORM and instead use node-postgres by itself.

I'm looking for examples as I'm new to Javascript.  I would guess wrapping things up in an object?

Here's an example of a 'show' customer express resource as it stands now.

```
exports.show = function(req, res, next) {
  pg.connect(conString, function(err, client) {
    client.query('select * from customer where id = ' + req.params.customer, function(err, results) {
      if (err) { throw next(err.message); } 
      var customer = results.rows[0];
      client.query('select * from history where customer_id = ' + req.params.customer + 
        ' order by updated_at desc', function(err, results) {
        if (err) { throw next(err.message); }
        var history = results.rows;
        client.query('select * from contacts where customer_id = ' + req.params.customer, function(err, results) {
          if (err) { return next(err.message); }
          var contacts = results.rows;
          res.render('customers/show', {
            title: 'Customer ' + customer.name,
            customer: customer, 
            history: history,
            contacts: contacts,
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
};
```

How can I refactor this towards a nice DAL?